# hierarchical database model - physical pointers

Tags: database, model, relational-database, hierarchical

I am reading a book about databases and I was wondering if someone could explain something that I can't understand / visualise. I have used relational databases and understand foreign keys etc. My question is, what is a "physical pointer" in a hierarchical data model?

> The earlier hierarchical data model is suitable for data structures that are naturally hierarchical, with each data structure placed at a certain level in the hierarchy. However, in the business arena, many of the data structures and their relationships cannot be readily placed in a hierarchical arrangement. The network data model evolved to dispense with the arbitrary restriction of the hierarchical model. **Nevertheless, in both of these models, you need physical pointers to connect related data occurrences. This is a serious drawback because you have rewrite the physical addresses in the data records every time you reorganize the data, move the data to a different storage area, or change over to another storage medium.** The relational model establishes the connections between related data occurrences by means of logical links implemented through foreign keys.

Ponniah, P. (2003) Database Design and Development: An Essential Guide for IT Professionals [Online], Hoboken, New Jersey, John Wiley & Sons. Available at http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/book/10.1002/0471728993

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A physical pointer is any value that indicates where something is located, e.g. a memory address, position in an array or collection, a file system path, OID, etc.

In contrast, the relational model identifies things by their own attributes - natural keys or assigned surrogate keys. This adds a layer of abstraction and complexity to the DBMS, but isolates users from the organization of system data structures.

For example, in hierarchical data structures, each child record might contain the address of its parent record, while a parent record might hold an array of its children's addresses.

Comment: What language and tool is used for creating and performing operation on databases which have used Hierarchical model? like for relational we have SQL server and other software tools and SQL Language.

Comment: @RafiO Hierarchical data is generally accessed and managed programmatically instead of having its own query language. If you've worked with XML or JSON data, you'll have some familiarity.

Comment: thank you @reaanb bro.one thing is still not clear for me that, what is meant by address, that it is said in hierarchical model parent node store address of child node.

Comment: @RafiO An address is a value that can be used to access a structure like a node or record. When one structure stores an address of another, it creates a link that can be used to navigate from the one to the other to obtain related data. In hierarchical and network models, links are generally efficient to navigate but very inefficient or impossible to lookup in reverse, i.e. to find all related structures pointing to a given one. The relational model on the other hand doesn't rely on addresses but on comparison of values (e.g. equality) to link records on demand.

Comment: Is this address the same as the address we store in pointer variable in c++?          Do we store address of the node where it is stored in hard disk.

Comment: @RafiO Hard disk or RAM addresses are one way of implementing it. It could also be array indices.